# select the com port of the device from drop down menu and blink the led corresponding to the selected com port

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python3.7.2 .Stuck in a problem where I need to code using tkinter to show all the ports of the connected devices in a drop down menu and then blink the led of the device corresponding to the selected com port.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough info to actually talk to a device, but pyserial can enumerate COM ports for you, feeding the ports list into tkinter control is rather stragit forward, here you go:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter import *

def on_select(selection):
    # open the port and command it to start the LED blinking here
    print(selection)

root = Tk()
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
default = StringVar(root, "Please Select Port")
OptionMenu(root, default, *ports, command=on_select).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thnkyou sir...i've already tried this...but when i add this to my whole code for blinking led...it does not work....i am not able to switch on/off the led of the device corresponding to the selected port...i am also using arduino code with this tkinter

Comment: Seeing your actual code and mentioning the specific error you get would help others to understand what going on and help you.